# Does node + socketio + express + https secure the socket data as well

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

With the following code snippet:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  server = require('https').createServer(app),
  io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/assets/html/index.html');
});
/** More routing functions **/

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    components.socket.onConnect(socket, config);
});
io.on('save', function(data){
  var saved = save(data);
  io.emit('response', saved);
});
/** More Socket.io functions **/

server.listen(443, function() {
  console.log("Server Ready.");
});
```

Assuming this server side setup (with ssl cert) and the clients connect securely, are the `data` value on `save` and the `saved` value emitted back with `socket.io` also encrypted with the ssl cert like the web data would be too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes as long as you use https for the initial connection. In your example, since you're only ever using https, this will never be a problem for you.